# Converting RGB to Gray scale?

Tags: vb.net, image

I am new to Visual Basic, I've done image processing in matlab in the past. But require Image Processing in Visual Basic as of this moment. Okay, I've been able to display the image and read up on converting to grayscale. However my image is in jpeg format and i keep running into the Bitmap function for only bmp images in several grayscale converter tutorials and my code keep producing errors for attempts in manipulation for JPEG format. How do i read in the jpeg and perform the grayscale manipulation. Here is the code.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub showButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles showButton.Click
    ' Show the Open File dialog. If the user clicks OK, load the
    ' picture that the user chose.
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        PictureBox1.Load(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub GrayImageButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GrayImageButton.Click
 Dim bm As New jpeg(PictureBox1.Image)
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim Y As Integer
    Dim clr As Integer

    For X = 0 To bm.Width - 1
        For Y = 0 To bm.Height - 1
            clr = (CInt(bm.GetPixel(X, Y).R) + _
                   bm.GetPixel(X, Y).G + _
                   bm.GetPixel(X, Y).B) \ 3
            bm.SetPixel(X, Y, Color.FromArgb(clr, clr, clr))
        Next Y
    Next X
    PictureBox1.Image = bm
End Sub
```

The error I'm recieving is

Error1 :  Value of type 'WindowsApplication1.jpeg' cannot be converted to 'System.Drawing.Image'.

When I implement this with a bmp image it works perfectly, but not with a jpeg. I will be grateful for any help with this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just change:

```
Dim bm As New jpeg(PictureBox1.Image)
```

To:

```
Dim bm As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
```

It would be **faster**, though, to use a ColorMatrix like this:

```
Private Sub GrayImageButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GrayImageButton.Click
    Dim grayscale As New Imaging.ColorMatrix(New Single()() _
        { _
            New Single() {0.299, 0.299, 0.299, 0, 0}, _
            New Single() {0.587, 0.587, 0.587, 0, 0}, _
            New Single() {0.114, 0.114, 0.114, 0, 0}, _
            New Single() {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, _
            New Single() {0, 0, 0, 0, 1} _
        })

    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)
    Dim imgattr As New Imaging.ImageAttributes()
    imgattr.SetColorMatrix(grayscale)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        g.DrawImage(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), _
                    0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height, _
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgattr)
    End Using
    PictureBox1.Image = bmp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is jpeg defined? Is that a VB.Net Library you are using? Or have you written this object yourself?

.Net has some built-in Jpeg utilities, you may want to check this out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.jpegbitmapdecoder.aspx

With this you should be able to access the pixels, from there your background in color manipulation should allow you to use this to do exactly what you are looking to do.

Comment: To display the Bitmap image, The code was in this format as shown above but for the second portion of the code above with the dimension Dim, i replace the jpeg and used Bitmap and it worked for BMP images. So i've visited the site, as i've come to understand,  the second source code file oon that page converts a jpeg in order for it to be accepatable in visual basic.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at an imaging library like AForge or OpenCV.  They have lots of useful functions built-in (several different RGB-to-Grayscale algorithms, for example).  OpenCV is written in C++ so it's probably going to be faster than anything you can write in VB.  I'm not sure about AForge, but I think it is written in C#.

Comment: Unfortunately sir, i'm unfamiliar with c++. This is preperation for a school lab and the lab leader is only familiar with Visual Basic for image processing not matlab. So I have all what I need in matlab, but not in VB As an engineering major, i've only dealt with matlab and c a while back.

Comment: You don't need to know C++.  You just import the OpenCV DLL and call it from within VB.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such type as `jpeg` in vb.net so the line:

```
Dim bm As New jpeg(PictureBox1.Image)
```

should be replaced by

```
Dim bm as Bitmap = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.image)
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a good code

Sub BlackAndWhite()
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer
        Dim red As Byte
        Dim green As Byte
        Dim blue As Byte
        For x = 0 To I.Width - 1
            For y = 0 To I.Height - 1
                red = I.GetPixel(x, y).R
                green = I.GetPixel(x, y).G
                blue = I.GetPixel(x, y).B
                I.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(blue, blue, blue))
            Next
        Next
        PictureBox1.Image = I
    End Sub